# Django URLs not matching with GET variables

Tags: django

I have the following django URL:

```
url(r'^companies/$', 'companies', name='companies'),
```

If I go to `http://localhost:8000/companies/` it works perfectly. However, if I try adding any GET variables to the URL django raises a 404. For example, if I go to `http://localhost:8000/companies/?c=1` django raises a 404. What's strange, is that on the 404 it says:

> The current URL, `companies/`, didn't match any of these.

Why am I not able to pass GET variables to my URLs?

I am using django 1.4.

The companies view is defined like:

```
def companies(request):
```

It shouldn't have to accept any additional parameters because they are GET variables, not URL parameters- correct?  I swear I've done this hundreds of times and it always just works...

Comment: Maybe your `companies` function doesn't accept any parameters? Show it signature, please

Comment: Added to question.  Just `def companies(request):`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay. Figured out what was causing this very strange behavior. I have a custom context processor that is calling `resolve(request.get_full_path())`. Apparently that causes a 404 if there are any GET variables in the URL.  Very strange.

Comment: Apparently this is a known [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13855). `resolve(request.path)` works, and fixes the 404's.

Comment: It's not strange at all. `request.get_full_path()` returns the URL path  *plus* the query string. However, `resolve` expects just a simple URL path, so it attempts to find a urlpattern that matches the string you passed in *including* the query string. Obviously, no such urlpattern would exist, so you get a 404. As you determined, you need to use `request.path` because that doesn't include the query string.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess what is weird is how the exception behaved- it didn't give me the bare 404 that occurs if you raise Http404, nor did it give me a traceback. It simply gave me the normal 404 as if a URL in my urls.conf didn't match- which it obviously did.

Comment: Again, that's exactly the case. It didn't match anything (due to the query string), so it gave you a standard 404, just as if you had tried to go to `/some/page/that/does/not/exist/`.